# Getting issue while inspecting mobile app through Appium

Tags: python-3.x, appium-ios, xcode13

Steps:

1. Running WebdriverAgent Lib, WebdriverAgent Runner, IntegrationApp in XCode then I am able to launch Simulator and app is also added but getting some issue in signing(debug)
2. When I am adding capabilities in Appium Inspector and trying to inspect app then Webdriver Agent is getting installed in simulator and deleting again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSvZ0.png)
Please share some solutions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use an existing bundle identifier that you already have added to this account or (not the best workaround) create a new free Apple developer account and sign WDA with it. Or you could wait a few days until the limitation is lifted. Also clean the project and build WDA from scratch on the device after making the changes at least once, then try connecting with Appium.

Comment: Is XCode 13.4 is compatible with appium version 1.22.3

Comment: It should be afaik, but I don't think that is related to the problem. You have issues signing the WebDriverAgent.